# Ansible Playbook skipping: no hosts matched

Tags: ansible

I have a directory where I created ansible.cfg, inventory_win and windesk.yml(my playbook).
In **ansible.cfg** I defined the following

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking=False
ansible_python_interpreter= /usr/bin/python3
hostfile = inventory_win
```

Inside **inventory_win** I have

```
myfirsthost ansible_host=192.168.10.30
my2ndthost2 ansible_host=192.168.10.34

[windesk]
myfirsthost
my2ndthost2

[datacenter:children]
windesk
```

In **windesk.yml**, I have

```
---

- hosts: windesk
  vars:
    ansible_site_path: "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\some\\"
    vsite: "Default Web Site"
    vsiteindexfile: "index3.html"
 
  tasks:
  - name: create new website's directory
    win_file: path={{ ansible_site_path }} state=directory

  - name: Create a virtual directory if it does not exist
    win_iis_virtualdirectory:
      name: somedirectroy
      site: "{{ vsite }}"
      state: present
      physical_path: "{{ ansible_site_path }}"
```

When I run

```
ansible-playbook windesk.yaml
```

I get

> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available.
> Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all' [WARNING]: Could
> not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: windesk
>
> PLAY [windesk]
> ******************************************************************************************** skipping: no hosts matched
>
> PLAY RECAP
>
> ---

but running

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory_win windesk.yaml
```

it works fine and I get the expected results

Answer (score 2):

Your definition in the `ansible.cfg` is incorrect. The [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-host-list) detail that the key name should be `inventory` not `hostfile`

> Description
> Comma separated list of Ansible inventory sources
>
> Type
> pathlist
>
> Default
> /etc/ansible/hosts
>
> Ini
> Section
> [defaults]
>
> Key
> inventory

```ini
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
ansible_python_interpreter =/ usr/bin/python3
inventory = inventory_win
```

**OUTPUT**

```bash
[centos@vps-f116ed9f stack_ansible]$ ansible-playbook windesk.yml -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.9.27
  config file = /home/centos/stack_ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/centos/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 28 2022, 15:30:04) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
Using /home/centos/stack_ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /home/centos/stack_ansible/inventory_win as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/centos/stack_ansible/inventory_win as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/centos/stack_ansible/inventory_win as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /home/centos/stack_ansible/inventory_win inventory source with ini plugin
```

Comment: Thanks, so again another deprecated flag